# does order of definitions influence result of synthesis?

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture

Of course that's impossible that order of definitions can influence result of synthesis. But I met this bug. When I test "MTC0" instruction of MIPS ISA in Modelsim.

[image]

These different order of definitions have different waveforms. The left one is wrong(all wrong at the beginning) while the right one is correct.

I didn't change any code except these.

I'm a fresh man on SO, so my reputation is too low to upload more images, which may cause you confused. I'm so sorry but I don't have any ideas.

Full code is posted on [Github](https://github.com/Wyp184800/restart). The "wishbone" folder is useless about this issue, just ignore it.

Comment: sorry, I don't know that then, I just signed up minutes ago before asking the question. And I will do it next time. Thank you for your answer and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstInvalid` has different values between the two definitions of the defines file.

```
1'b0 on the left (incorrect waveform)
1'b1 on the right (correct waveform)
```

Change the incorrect (left version) to the 1'b1 value and rerun, does this correct the run time issue!

Comment: Yes. That's the problem. But,can you explain it? I don't know why this causes different waveform.

Comment: That seems to be a static signal output from id.v. It is part of [output excepttype_o](https://github.com/Wyp184800/restart/blob/12a327154245aa2b35f3a84612581748eba25503/OpenMipsFromBook/id.v#L108).

Comment: No problem, it often helps to have fresh eyes look at a bug.